# Multithreading doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I'm making a simple multithreading program to explain the working of threading. I want two counters counting on the same time but it doesn't work.

It only works if I use: `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False`. But, I want to program in a proper way.

Code:

```
Dim Thread1 As System.Threading.Thread
Dim Thread2 As System.Threading.Thread

Private Delegate Sub SetTeller1()

Private Sub teller1()
    If teller1Label.InvokeRequired Then
        Invoke(New SetTeller1(AddressOf teller1))
    Else
        For i As Integer = 0 To 1000
            teller1Label.Text = i
            Refresh()
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Delegate Sub SetTeller2()

Private Sub teller2()
    If teller2Label.InvokeRequired Then
        Invoke(New SetTeller2(AddressOf teller2))
    Else
        For i As Integer = 0 To 1000
            teller2Label.Text = i
            Refresh()
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub teller1Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles teller1Button.Click
    Thread1 = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf teller1)
    Thread1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub teller2Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles teller2Button.Click
    Thread2 = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf teller2)
    Thread2.Start()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The multithreading works perfectly, but you are not utilizing it. The only thing you're currently doing in the background thread is calling `Invoke`, which means that your thread will exit within a few milliseconds and then be discarded.

Once you call `Invoke` the execution of the `teller1` or `teller2` method is moved to the UI thread, meaning it will block the UI until its execution is finished. You should only invoke *when you are to update the UI*, and perform all iterations in the background thread.

Here's an example of how you can do it more properly:

```
Delegate Sub SetTeller1(ByVal Text As String)

Private Sub teller1()
    For i As Integer = 0 To 1000
        SetTeller1Text(i)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub SetTeller1Text(ByVal Text As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New SetTeller1(AddressOf SetTeller1Text), Text)
    Else
        teller1Label.Text = Text
        Me.Refresh()
    End If
End Sub
```

For improved readability I changed for example `Invoke(...)` to `Me.Invoke(...)`.

Also I'm not sure why you're calling `Refresh()` as it isn't necessary and will just cause extra redrawing of the entire container (guessing this is a form).